# Metric space with an uncountable subset containing points separated by distance greater than one

Tags: metric-spaces

Let $\langle X,d \rangle$ be a metric space such that there is an uncountable set $Y \subseteq X$ such that any two distinct points of $Y$ have distance greater than one. Show that $X$ is not separable.

I know [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/917232/1177243) is a very similar problem, but that one involves a fixed distance between points in the subset, not a lower bound. Also, I can't make sense of any of the answers.

Edit: To clarify, I don't understand the answers to the linked problem. One claims that if $\alpha$ is this fixed distance, then for every element in the subset there is always an element in the metric space that is at most $\frac{\alpha}{4}$ away. I don't understand why this is forced, or how the solution proceeds from there.
Another answer claims the subset is discrete, which I also don't see.
The last one seems good, but I think it claims that the metric space being separable implies that this uncountable subset is also separable. Is that true?

Comment: The same approach works: in answer to question you linked we don't actually need distance between points of $Y$ to be exactly $\alpha$, it's enough that it's at least $\alpha$.

Comment: Separability is not hereditary but second-countability is,   and for metric spaces, these two properties are equivalent. This is why "the metric space being separable implies that this uncountable subset is also separable".

Comment: Thank you! That was the last piece of the puzzle I needed

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Every subspace of a separable metric space is separable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3535949/every-subspace-of-a-separable-metric-space-is-separable)

Comment: "*[One claims that](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/917241/386889) if α is this fixed distance, then for every element in the subset there is always an element in the metric space that is at most $α/4$ away":* not anywhere in the metric space $X$ (otherwise you could as well uselessly take $a(x)=x$) but in a dense subset $A.$ *"why this is forced":* by definition of "$A$ is dense in $X$". *"or how the solution proceeds from there":* $a:M\to A$ is injective because if $x\ne x',$ $d(a(x),a(x'))\ge d(x,x')-d(x,a(x))-d(a(x'),x)\geα-α/4-α/4>0.$ Hence every dense subset $A$ of $X$ is uncountable.

Comment: "*[Another answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/917243/386889) claims the subset is discrete, which I also don't see":* for every $x\in M,$ $\{x\}$ is an open subset of $M,$ since it is equal to $B(x,α/2)\cap M.$ In my opinion, the best answer was the one explained in my previous comment. [The accepted one](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/917254/386889) (explained by my first comment above or by the proposed duplicate) was flawed, but I corrected it in a comment.